# Regex for URL in python

Tags: python, regex

```
url1='http://.www.youtube.com/watch?v=tKTZoB2Vjuk&index=1&list=PLqmh7e11V6OzWBTSYNq1yYznar709uDQx'
#url2='www.ssa.gov/cgi-bin/popularnames.cgi'
def verify(url):
    try:
        x=re.search('((^https|http|ftp):)?(/?/?www)\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}\/[-a-zA-Z0-9?=&%#./]*',url)
        print x.group()

    except:
        print "not valid"

verify(url1)
```

Shouldnt this URL be invalid as there is a dot before www?

My output shows:

```
www.youtube.com/watch?v=tKTZoB2Vjuk&index=1&list=PLqmh7e11V6OzWBTSYNq1yYznar709uDQx
```

Comment: Relevant: https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex

Comment: But all of the bits **before** `www` are optional, so they just get skipped (see e.g. https://regex101.com/r/cW6gI9/1)! Add a `^` at the start (*outside* the opening parentheses) if you want the regex to be anchored to the start of the string, and use `match` rather than `search`

Comment: "and use `match`" should be *"or* use `match`" since the `^` isn't necessary at all with `match`.

Answer (score 0):

Only `https` is anchored to the beginning of the string and the protocol group is marked optional. Thus, your regex will match any text that *contains* a URI (as defined by the regex) as long as it doesn't need to start with `https`.

I'd recommend removing the `^` entirely and using `re.match` rather than `re.search`.

Your regex has other problems that will prevent it matching other perfectly valid URIs.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down your regex:

```
(                    # begin group
  (^https|http|ftp): # protocol (and only https needs to be at the start)
)?                   # end optional group
(                    # start group
  /?/?               # optional slashes
  www                # www
)                    # end group
...
```

From the above, you can see that both protocol and slashes are optional, so all your regex requires is www somewhere, regardless of what's at the start.